# Convert DataTable to nestead Class by linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, inner-classes

I have a nested class definition as below:

```
[XmlRoot()]
public class cars
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="car")]
    public car[] carList { get; set; }
}
public class car
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "manufacture")]
    public string manufacture { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "models")]
    public models modelList { get; set; }
}
public class models
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "model")]
    public model[] modelList { get; set; }
}
public class model
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "color")]
    public string color { get; set; }
}
```

I have a DataTable as below:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Manufacture");
    dt.Columns.Add("ModelName");
    dt.Columns.Add("Color");

    Object[] rows = { 
        new Object[]{"P1","405","1,6"},
        new Object[]{"P1","406","1,7"},
        new Object[]{"P2","407","1,8"}，
        new Object[]{"P2","408","1,9"}
    };
    dt.Rows.Add(rows);
```

I want to convert my data in DataTable to my class cars.
Any help would be appreciated.
Update:
For using suggestion, I need to change Rows.Add with below code, otherwise, I will only get object in result.

```
            DataRow dr= dt.NewRow();
        dr["Manufacture"] = "Peugeot1";
        dr["ModelName"] = "405";
        dr["Color"] = "1,6";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        DataRow dr2 = dt.NewRow();
        dr2["Manufacture"] = "Peugeot1";
        dr2["ModelName"] = "406";
        dr2["Color"] = "1,7";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr2);
        DataRow dr3 = dt.NewRow();
        dr3["Manufacture"] = "Peugeot2";
        dr3["ModelName"] = "405";
        dr3["Color"] = "1,6";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr3);
```

Comment: Loop rows and pass column values to the correspondent property of `Car` class

Comment: Is there any particular reason to create `models` class that represents an array of `model` class instead of using an array of `model` class directly inside `car` class?

Comment: @SomeUser yes, I use this class to create xml document, I need models node for model list node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GroupBy` to group all the rows by the `Manufacture` and then for each group project a new `Car`. To populate the `ModelList` property use a `Select` on the group:

```
var result = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
              group row by row.Field<string>("Manufacture") into grouping
              select new Car
              {
                  Manufacture = grouping.Key,
                  ModelList = grouping.Select(item => new Model
                  {
                      Name = item.Field<string>("ModelName"),
                      Color = item.Field<string>("Color")
                  }).ToArray()
              }).ToList();
```

You can also use the method syntax with the `GroupBy` overload where you specify a selector predicate:

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .GroupBy(row => row.Field<string>("Manufacture"),
                        row => new Model
                        {
                            Name = row.Field<string>("ModelName"),
                            Color = row.Field<string>("Color")
                        })
               .Select(group => new Car
               {
                   Manufacture = group.Key,
                   ModelList = group.ToArray()
               }).ToList();
```

*Note that I have change the classes and property names to match the C# naming conventions*

Comment: thanks for your help. it is much helpful. One more issues, with your code, I need to change my DataTable to add new records by setting column value( refer code in original post). If i use my original way to add rows, it will return object instead of real values. Could you share me why this happened.

Comment: thanks, I found my problem, my first way is wrong, now it works by adding row loop through rows.

Comment: @Edward - pleased my answer helped and also that you managed to fix the next problem :)